# Splitting file processing by initial keys

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

#### Use Case

I have some terabytes of US property data to merge. It is spread across two distinct file formats and thousands of files. The source data is split geographically.

I can't find a way to branch a single pipeline into many independent processing flows.

This is especially difficult because the `Dataframe` API doesn't seem to support a `PTransform` on a collection of filenames.

#### Detailed Background

The distribution of files is like this:

- StateData - 51 total files (US states + DC)
- CountyData - ~2000 total files (county specific, grouped by state)

The ideal pipeline would split into thousands of independent processing steps and complete in minutes.

- 1 -> 51 (each US state + DC starts processing)
- 51 -> thousands (each US state then spawns a process that merges the counties, combining at the end for the whole state)

The directory structure is like this:

```
state-data/
 |-AL.zip
 |-AK.zip
 |-...
 |-WY.zip
county-data/
 |-AL/
   |-COUNTY1.csv
   |-COUNTY2.csv
   |-...
   |-COUNTY68.csv
 |-AK/
   |-...
 |-.../
 |-WY/
   |-...
```

#### Sample Data

This is extremely abbreviated, but imagine something like this:

**State Level Data** - 51 of these (~200 cols wide)

| uid | census_plot | flood_zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc121 | ACVB-1249575 | R50 |
| abc122 | ACVB-1249575 | R50 |
| abc123 | ACVB-1249575 | R51 |
| abc124 | ACVB-1249599 | R51 |
| abc125 | ACVB-1249599 | R50 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**County Level Data** - thousands of these (~300 cols wide)

| uid | county | subdivision | tax_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc121 | 04021 | Roland Heights | 3t4g |
| abc122 | 04021 | Roland Heights | 3g444 |
| abc123 | 04021 | Roland Heights | 09udd |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

So we join many county-level to a single state level, and thus have an aggregated, more-complete state-level data set.

Then we aggregate all the states, and we have a national level data set.

#### Desired Outcome

I can successfully merge one state at a time (many county to one state). I built a pipeline to do that, but the pipeline starts with a single CountyData CSV and a single StateData CSV. The issue is getting to the point where I can load the CountyData and StateData.

In other words:

```
#
# I need to find a way to generalize this flow to
# dynamically created COUNTY and STATE variables.
#

from apache_beam.dataframe.convert import to_pcollection
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv

COUNTY = "county-data/AL/*.csv"
STATE = "state-data/AL.zip"

def key_by_uid(elem):
    return (elem.uid, elem)

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    county_df = p | read_csv(COUNTY)
    county_rows_keyed = to_pcollection(county_df) | beam.Map(key_by_uid)

    state_df = pd.read_csv(STATE, compression="zip")
    state_rows_keys = to_pcollection(state_df, pipeline=p) | beam.Map(key_by_uid)

    merged = ({ "state": state_rows_keys, "county": county_rows_keyed } ) | beam.CoGroupByKey() | beam.Map(merge_logic)

    merged | WriteToParquet()
```

1. Starting with a list of states
2. By state, generate filepatterns to the source data
3. By state, load and merge the filenames
4. Flatten the output from each state into a US data set.
5. Write to Parquet file.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    merged_data = (
        p
        | beam.Create(cx.STATES)
        | "PathsKeyedByState" >> tx.PathsKeyedByState()
        # ('AL', {'county-data': 'gs://data/county-data/AL/COUNTY*.csv', 'state-data': 'gs://data/state-data/AL.zip'})
        | "MergeSourceDataByState" >> tx.MergeSourceDataByState()
        | "MergeAllStateData" >> beam.Flatten()
    )

    merged_data | "WriteParquet" >> tx.WriteParquet()
```

The issue I'm having is something like this:

- I have two filepatterns in a dictionary, per state. To access those I need to use a `DoFn` to get at the element.
- To communicate the way the data flows, I need access to `Pipeline`, which is a `PTransform`. Ex: `df = p | read_csv(...)`
- These appear to be incompatible needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative answer.

Read the state data one at a time and flatten them, e.g.

```
state_dataframe = None
for state in STATES:
  df = p | read_csv('/path/to/state')
  df['state'] = state
  if state_dataframe is None:
    state_dataframe = df
  else:
    state_dataframe = state_dataframe.append(df)
```

Similarly for county data. Now join them using dataframe operations.

Comment: Thanks - I confirm that this works. A for-loop seems to defeat the purpose of Beam, though, right? Is this magically parallelizable?

Comment: Really what's happening here is that a deferred execution tree is being built up, until the Pipeline's with block is exited, at which point the entire thing is run. The pipeline as a whole is then optimized and all reads executed in parallel.

Comment: This is the missing piece in my understanding. Thanks. The problem is now trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of merging you're doing here, but one way to structure this pipeline might be to have a DoFn that takes the county data in as a filename as an input element (i.e. you'd have a PCollection of county data filenames), opens it up using "normal" Python (e.g. pandas), and then reads the relevant state data in as a side input to do the merge.

Comment: Imagine data that's incomplete in each source. We will just do the equiv. of `JOIN` on from table `STATE` to many `COUNTY` tables. I'm interested in the `side input` method here -- I already need to use `pandas` on the state-level data because it's actually `.zip` and we can't specify `compression` as a `read_csv` option yet.

Comment: I added some very simple sample data.

Comment: It’s possible the way forward is to use `beam.pvalue` within the transform, as noted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845793/how-to-supply-parameters-to-a-composite-transform-in-apache-beam

Comment: I found your TODO  in `_ReadFromPandasDoFn` :-)  I simply need to repurpose your code in the associated transform to accommodate many paths instead of one.

Comment: This failed, for the same reasons the original approach failed. I can't figure out how to access the root pipeline and individual element data at the same time.